# A question related to system of Distinct Representatives ( Q 11, Ch -9 , Richard Brualdi)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am self studying Combinatorics from Richard Brualdi Elementary Combinatorics .

In chapter - System Of Distinct Representatives I am unable to solve this question ( Q no. 11) .
Let  > 1 and let  = ${A_1,A_2 , … ,A_n}$ be a family of subsets of {1, 2, … , }, with $A_i$ = {1, 2, … , } − {}.
Prove that  has an SDR and the number of SDRs is n th  derangement number $D_n$ .

> My Attempt -> It is easy to see why SDR exists(By Marriage  Condition) . But I am unable to prove that $D_n$ is equivalent to the codition give in the Question .

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$ is a derangement, $\langle\pi(1),\pi(2),\ldots,\pi(n)\rangle$ is an SDR: for each $k\in[n]$ we have $\pi(k)\ne k$, so $\pi(k)\in A_k$. The converse is really just the same idea: if $\langle a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\rangle$ is an SDR, then the permutation $\pi:[n]\to[n]:k\mapsto a_k$ is a derangement, since $a_k\notin A_k$ for $k\in[n]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the distinct representatives be $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$.  By hypothesis, $a_i\neq i,\ i=1,2\dots,n$.  That is, $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ is a derangement of $1,2,\dots,n$.